# RPM package name changed after publishing from Teamcity to Artifactory

Tags: build.gradle, teamcity, artifactory

My RPM package name was (for example) testing-1.0.0.rpm, however when i did an artifactoryPublish the .rpm name was changed to 1745789basf.1.0.0.rpm.

I did a check on my teamcity directory to check if it was because the osPackage that was responsible to build to RPM was wrong, but it was showing the correct name, testing-1.0.0.rpm.

Why will the name of the package change when publishing from teamcity to artifactory? How can i make sure the name is not changed?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Jenkins with artifactory while uploading to artifactory there is an option to upload with the custom name. In case that is left blank it will take the default one. In case of Team city I feel like the same is happening.

Can you check for such settings in Team City wherein there is an option to set the name